# fs.existsSync is not a function error when requiring grpc through create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, grpc

We are trying to get gRPC to work with React (actually we were trying to get it to work with React-Native but gave up on that for now).

Using plain node.js things are pretty straight forward if you follow [this example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/node/dynamic_codegen/greeter_client.js).

We started by using create-react-app but when we started the app, we got the following error:

```
existsSync is not a function
```

That was casued by this bit in pre-binding.js belonging to the node-pre-gyp package located in grpc:

```
var existsSync = require('fs').existsSync || require('path').existsSync;
```

My understanding is that something goes on with Webpack (or some other process run by create-react-app) that goes and returns and empty object instead of `require('fs')`.

Any ideas of how to get this to work without having to give up on the wonders of create-react-app?

To test it out you can just follow these 2 easy steps:

1. create-react-app test-app
2. add `import grpc from 'grpc';` in the App.js file

Comment: Grpc is to create the server, shouldn't you use: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web instead? (i'm just saying what i read in the docs)

Comment: I just want to clarify: is this React app something that is supposed to run in a browser?

Comment: Indeed, while this works fine on node.js as a client (the grpc npm package works as a client too) the problem is running this client on a browser vs through node. It seems we do have to use grpc-web one way or another and this from what I understand means that the server cannot use a tcp connection but rather an http one (with TLS in order to use http2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, from what I understand now, you are not really supposed to use gRPC + Protobuf directly from any frontend but rather it is more common to use the `grpc` node package on node.js server-side code and then communicate with the browser-side code using Express.

The server-side code on node.js then communicates using `grpc` with the microservices.

We are testing out the use of Firebase Functions to communicate securely with the frontend and Firebase Functions communicate with the Go microservices using `grpc`.